# Understanding conditional probability in a problem

Tags: conditional-probability

The problem is as follows:

> Senior students tend to stay up all night and therefore are not able
> to wake up on time in morning. Not only this but their dependence on
> tuitions further leads to absenteeism in school. Of the students in
> class XII, it is known that 30% of the students have 100% attendance.
> Previous year results report that 80% of all students who have 100%
> attendance attain A grade and 10% irregular students attain A grade in
> their annual examination. At the end of the year, one student is
> chosen at random from the class XII.

> Find the conditional probability that a student attains A grade given that he is not
> 100 % regular student.

**My working:**

I made a map of how the events occur below, and with that, it can be inferred that the probability 'Grade A' obtained by an irregular student is:

$$ = P(being \ irregular)P(Grade A)$$
$$ = \frac{7}{10} \frac{1}{10} $$

[image]

However, the answer given in my book is $\frac{1}{10} $.

I don't really get any idea of how it is possible. From a group of 100 students, it is probable that 70 of them are irregular and among them, $70 \frac{1}{10}$ - which is 7 students out of the hundred.

But on deeper thought, since the problems ask the probability of getting grade A among the irregulars, the probability becomes $\frac{7}{70}$.

Now my question is, what should the question be, such that i get the answer -  $\frac{7}{10} \frac{1}{10}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the answer $\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}$, the new question can be: "What is the probability that the randomly chosen student is an irregular student, who scores an A?".

In this case you would have these calculations
$$P(\text{Grade A and No 100%})=P(\text{No 100%})\cdot P(\text{Grade A}|\text{No 100%})=\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}$$
("$\text{Grade A}|\text{No 100%}$" reads as "Grade A, given No $100\%$")

The original question was asking for the **conditional probability**. It was basically asking "What fraction of irregular students scores an A?".

This is why you would have these calculations and the textbook's answer
$$P(\text{Grade A}|\text{No 100%})=\frac{P(\text{Grade A and No 100%})}{P(\text{No 100%})}=\frac{\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}}{\frac{7}{10}}=\frac{1}{10}$$

Hope this helps and feel free to ask further questions, if this is a bit unclear! :)

Comment: The answer was really helpful! Apart from this question, I find a lot of questions where language becomes a problem for me :p. Well, now I won't miss a mark in my finals! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is trivial - it *gives* you that if a student does not have perfect attendance, the probability that they make an A is $10\% = \frac{1}{10}$.

If you want to use the definition of conditional probability here, you can first calculate the probability that a student does not have perfect attendance, which is $1 - 30\% = 70\% = \frac{7}{10}$. Then, the probability that a random student does not have perfect attendance and still makes an A is $10\% (1 - 30\%) = 7\% = \frac{7}{100}$. By Bayes, the probability that a student makes A given that he or she does not have perfect attendance is $\frac{\frac{7}{100}}{\frac{7}{10}} = \frac{1}{10}$.

To answer your question, the answer to

> What is the probability that a randomly-selected student (from the general senior population) does not perfect attendance and makes an A?

would be $\frac{7}{100}$.